# How can I get the box with text to stick to the top of each wrap div?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure it out without using float:right or using relative positioning. If I use either, it will move around when people zoom in and out. I'm trying to figure out how to make it stay exactly where I place it even when people zoom in and out.

http://htmlcss.netii.net/

**HTML Structure:**

```
<div class="staff-block">           
    <img class="staff-pics" />

    <div class="staff-text">
        <h3>
        <p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.staff-block { /* Red */
    border: 1px dashed red;
    display: block;  

}

.staff-pics { /* Orange */
    border: 1px dashed orange;
  display: ;
  width:150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.staff-text { /* Yellow */
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFCC00;
  display: inline-block;
}

.staff-text h3 { /* Green */
    border: 1px dashed lime;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.staff-text p { /* Blue */
    border: 1px dashed aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are already `inline-block` elements, simply add `vertical-align:top`.

```
.staff-text {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It works - I tested it via the dev tool in Chrome..

Updated CSS:

```
.staff-text {
    border: 1px dashed lime;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFCC00;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the vertical-align property

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work outside the dev tool when I just open it with text editor.

Comment: @ekedin It should work - check the dev tool to see if anything is being overwritten.. there might also be chaching.. Otherwise add `vertical-align:top` to both `divs`

Comment: ya, it must still have the other page cached. the v-align wasn't in the page even though I put it in my css.